# Developing REST API with Nodejs and multiple Database connection in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to develop APIs for an application which is like a job searching platform. So far so good everything working fine. But I have a requirement, that I'd like to move the records of inactive users to one another DB and clear it from the current DB.

So, if I'm using one MongoDB cluster for storing the data the history of inactive users DB will be in another cluster. But the problem comes when creating multiple connections in mongoose and dynamically changing the connection URL.

I have found that one mongoose connection will be used throughout one node application. So if I use multiple connections like User1 is using the connection1 and when user2 comes online he tends to use the backup DB. So the app changes to use connection2. Will this affect the USer1???

And how to handle these multiple connections dynamically?

I got one code but it will handle DBs from the same server. And in all routes need to create a connection and select the DB.

The code is as follows

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const db = require('./utils/db')
const userRoute = require('./routes/user-route')

const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    limit: '50mb',
    extended: true
}));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
  );
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE');

  next();
});

global.clientConnection = db.initClientDbConnection();

app.use('/user', userRoute)

app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log(`Application running at PORT 5000`);
});
```

**utils/db.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const clientOption = {
  socketTimeoutMS: 30000,
  keepAlive: true,
  reconnectTries: 30000,
  poolSize: 50,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  autoIndex: false
};
const option = { useNewUrlParser: true };

const initClientDbConnection = () => {
  const db = mongoose.createConnection(`mongodb://localhost:27017/`, clientOption);

  db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB Connection Error>> : "));
  db.once("open", function() {
    console.log("client MongoDB Connection ok!");
  });
  require('../models/user-model')
  return db;
};

module.exports = {
  initClientDbConnection
};
```

**routes/user.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')

router.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const phoneNumber = '1234567890';
    const password = 'qwertyuiop';
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
    //accesing our cluster  connection from global object
    const dbConnection = await global.clientConnection;
    const db = await dbConnection.useDb('multipledbone'); //here using static db name
    const User = await db.model("User");
    const userPresent = await User.findOne({
            phoneNumber: phoneNumber
        });
    if(userPresent) {
      throw new Error('User Already Present')
    }
    const newUser = await new User({
            phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
            password: hashedPassword,
            email: 'testemail@email.com'
        }).save();
    res.send('Sucess')
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).send(err.message)
  }
})

router.get('/details', async (req, res) => {
  let user, db, User
  const { dbName } = req.body //here I specify the dbname via user input
  console.log(dbName);
  try {
    const dbConnection = await global.clientConnection;
    const db = await dbConnection.useDb(dbName);
    const User = await db.model("User");
    user = await User.findOne({phoneNumber: "1234567890"})
    if (!user) {
      res.send('no user')
    }
    res.send(user)
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(404).send(err.message)
  }
})

module.exports = router
```

**models/user.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,

    },
    phoneNumber: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,

    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
}, {
    toJSON: {
        virtuals: true
    },
    toObject: {
        virtuals: true
    },
    timestamps: true
});

userSchema.index({
    userId: 1
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

The solutions I need

- Able to dynamically set the connection URL

Comment: pass URL from ENV variables if possible OR use config file

Comment: Thats for one DB. I want to change the DB url dynamically.

Comment: Dynamic means how? can you explain a bit more?